# Devuelve el carácter más repetido

Tags: python, string, bucles, diccionarios

El problema trata de devolver el carácter más repetido de la cadena, y si dos caracteres se repiten el mismo número de veces deberemos de retornar el posterior.

```
def letra_mas_comun(cadena:str)->str:
cadena = cadena.replace(" ","")
cadena.lower()
letras_dict = {}
for letra in cadena:
    if letra in letras_dict:
        letras_dict[letra] += 1
    else:
        letras_dict[letra] = 1
for letra in letras_dict:
    mas_repetida = 0
    resultado = ""
    if mas_repetida < letras_dict[letra]:
        mas_repetida = letras_dict[letra]
        resultado = letra
    elif mas_repetida == letras_dict[letra]:
        if letra > resultado:
            mas_repetida = letras_dict[letra]
            resultado = letra
        
return resultado
```

cadena = "hola soy maria"

print(letra_mas_comun(cadena))

Como resultado obtengo "i", el diccionario que realizo me da coherente con las repeticiones de cada letra pero no sé porque me da i. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: La variable mas_repetida está dentro de for inicializada a 0 por lo tanto nunca guardarás el valor que asignas mas adelante. Pon *mas_repetida=0* antes del for. Al igual que *resultado*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error está en que en cada iteración, vuelves a inicializar las variables de interés:

```
for letra in letras_dict:
    mas_repetida = 0
    resultado = ""
```

Lo correcto es inicializar antes de entrar al ciclo donde se modificarán:

```
mas_repetida = 0
resultado = ""
for letra in letras_dict:
```

Además, la comparación se puede simplificar, ya que sólo te interesa el caso en donde la letra actual sea más repetida que las anteriores. Con eso el ciclo queda reducido a:

```
for letra in letras_dict:
    if mas_repetida <= letras_dict[letra]:
        mas_repetida = letras_dict[letra]
        resultado = letra
```

#### Demo

```
def letra_mas_comun(cadena: str) -> str:
    cadena = cadena.replace(" ", "")
    cadena.lower()
    letras_dict = {}

    for letra in cadena:
        if letra in letras_dict:
            letras_dict[letra] += 1
        else:
            letras_dict[letra] = 1

    mas_repetida = 0
    resultado = ""
    for letra in letras_dict:
        if mas_repetida < letras_dict[letra]:
            mas_repetida = letras_dict[letra]
            resultado = letra

    return resultado

cadena = "hola soy maria"

print(letra_mas_comun(cadena)) # => a
```

Comment: Hola maestro, en el **if** debería ir **<=** para que cuando haya cantidades repetidas, muestre la que aparece en segundo lugar.

Comment: @MarcePuente. +1